# IList comparison not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists that I am trying to compare, sadly they are not of the save class. One is from the magento api and the other is a custom class containing some values from the other. (only the ones that I need)

```
if (existingPhotoOrders.Where(x => x.OrderNumber.CompareTo(order.increment_id) == 0).ToList().Count > 0)
                continue;
```

There is a problem with the API where I have to get all the orders and compare the ones that I want and then request individually extra information but the above query is not working it is just continueing with everything.

I have looked at other comparisons but they all require the classes to be the same. If anyone could shed some light I would be grateful.

Comment: You are asking about a loop. So include that loop.

Comment: Of what type is OrderNumber and increment_id? If they are different, this could cause the CompareTo not return as excpected.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
@HenkHolterman - I don't think that the loop was relevant, apolagies.
Matthias the OrderNumber and increment_id are the same value both strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be re-written like so using the `Any` method:

```
if (existingPhotoOrders.Any(x => x.OrderNumber.CompareTo(order.increment_id) == 0))
    continue;
```

As to why it is always continuing, the expression must always be true! I presume the requirement is `if the order increment id is not an order number of an existing order then continue`, in which case, you can use the `All` method:

```
if (existingPhotoOrders.All(x => x.OrderNumber.CompareTo(order.increment_id) != 0))
    continue;
```

Or as a more performant alternative:

```
var orderIds = new HashSet<int>(existingPhotoOrders.Select(epo => epo.OrderNumber));
foreach (var order in orders)
{
  if (!orderIds.Contains(order.increment_id))
  {
    continue;
  }
  // rest of method here
}
```

Comment: Rich, thank you for your help, I am very grateful. You have solved my problem! I chose to use your second example straight out with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `x` and the type of `order` are not important, however the types of `OrderNumber` and `increment_id`. Of what types are they?

If one is `string` and the other `int` then you should convert the `int` to `string`:

```
.Where(x => x.OrderNumber == order.increment_id.ToString())
```